# Unable to download payment manifest "https://pay.google.com/gp/p/payment_method_manifest.json" braintree integration

Tags: javascript, google-pay, manifest.json

[image: 1]

When I navigate to checkout page the I get this error message Unable to download payment manifest "https://pay.google.com/gp/p/payment_method_manifest.json". As the google pay is not active yet. This error message show only on edge browser.

Braintree integration

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug but should not cause any issues during the integration of Google Pay.

**Update**: Issue got fixed on Google Pay side and the error message is no longer showing.